# On the Visual Hiding of Node Connection Lines

Tags: omnet++

Suppose I connect the router to two nodes in the ned file

```
router1.pppg[0] <--> pppline <--> extRouter.pppg[0];
router2.pppg[0] <--> pppline <--> extRouter.pppg[1];
```

So in the simulation interface, you can clearly see these two ppline lines, so what should I do to hide these two lines in the simulation interface

Comment: "Sorry, this should be a problem with the OMNeT++program, but it is clear that I added the OMNeT++tag while editing, but it appears that there is no"

Answer (score 1):

Use `@display` property, that way:

```
router1.pppg[0] <--> pppline {@display("ls=,0");} <--> extRouter.pppg[0];
router2.pppg[0] <--> pppline {@display("ls=,0");} <--> extRouter.pppg[1];
```

Reference: [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:graphics:connection-displaystrings).

Comment: Thank you. I have a problem now, I have an AodvRouter node. At this point, I want to connect it to another route node. The two can communicate with each other. What should I do? Can you suggest some methods and code. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest asking a new question, providing enough information about your problem, including [mcve].

Comment: Thank you. I have a new question. I hope to receive your help. Thank you very much